# Get the value of button and save in db on click

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to update a field in db as 1 or 0 when i click on yes or no button..

```
<td>  <input type="button" onClick="save();" value="Yes">
     <input type="button" onClick="save();" value="No">
     </td>
```

This code displays the button in view page as yes and no. Now what should i do to save in db while clicking on yes button?

```
     <div class="bit-4 pad-small"  style="float:none;">
        <br>
        <br>
     <?php echo $this->Form->input('approve', array(
                              'type'=>'checkbox', 
                               'style' => 'float:left;',)
                                 ) ); ?>
           <span>required</span>
          </div>
```

Comment: yea sure :) wait a minute

Answer (score 0):

in your cakephp file you can get the value and update it to database. Hope you can get any way to update it now. Even you can do that in save() method.

/*please change input to any unique selecter give any id or class to button*/

```
    $("input").click(function(){

        var val = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({url: "path_to_your_cake_php_file.php", 

                    type: 'post', // performing a POST request
                    data : {
                      inputValue : val // will be accessible in $_POST['inputValue']
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result){
                    alert('value has been updated');
            }});

    })
```

Comment: <script>
              $("input").click(function(){

        var val = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({url: "add.ctp", 

                    type: 'post', // performing a POST request
                    data : {
                      inputValue : val // will be accessible in $_POST['inputValue']
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result){
                    alert('value has been updated');
            }});

    })
    </script>

Comment: wrap that into 
$(document).ready(function(){
 // user code is here
});

and you must have jquery included in your page .

Comment: can you make a method in your cakephp file e.g updateValue(){

}

Comment: its seems like you can not use ajax i give you one more simple way .. create your html like that .. 

<form id="myForm" method="Post" action="your_controller_method_path">
 <input type="button" onClick="save1();" value="Yes">
</form>
<form id="myForm2" method="Post" action="your_controller_method_path">
 <input type="button" onClick="save2();" value="No">
</form>
<script>
function save1(){
 document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}

function save2(){
 document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
</script>
and can you now create controller accroding to form action

Answer (score 0):

onclick function should have parameter that indicates which answer was submitted.

```
function save(id)
{
    var id = id;
    switch(id)
    {
        case 1:
            var buttonValue = "Yes";
            break;
        case 2:
            var buttonValue = "No";
            break;
    }
    var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("ButtonValue", buttonValue);
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            {
                var array = xmlHttp.responseText;
                //in array you store results echoed from php script
            }
        } 
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "file.php");
        xmlHttp.send(formData);
}
```

file.php

```
<?php 
    $buttonValue = $_POST["ButtonValue"];
    $con = mysqli_connect("host", "name", "pass", "db");
        $res = mysqli_query($con, "Insert goes here");
        mysqli_close($con);    
?>
```

PS Consider that pure JavaScript is nearly 30 times faster than JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and jquery-ajax for this.

HTML:

```
<td>  <input type="button" onClick="save(this);" value="Yes">
     <input type="button" onClick="save(this);" value="No">
     </td>
```

JS:

```
function save(elem){
     val = $(elem).val() == 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: Your_php_file_path,
      data: {button: val },
      success: function(data){
           //added 
       },
      dataType: json
     });

    }
```

In the server side you can get submitted value by `$_REQUEST['button']`

Comment: <tr ><td><?php echo $tdata['pay_date']; ?></td><td><?php echo $tdata['cylinder']; ?></td>
    <td>  <input type="button" onClick="save(this);" value="Yes">
     <input type="button" onClick="save(this);" value="No">
     </td>
        
      </tr>
           <?php
           endforeach;  
           ?>
           <script>
             function save(elem){
     val = $(elem).val() == 'Yes' ? 1 : 0;
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: index.ctp,
      data: {button: val },
      success: function(data){
           //added 
       },
      dataType: json
     }); } </script>

Comment: Please learn debugging first. Sorry, I do not have enough time to check your code base now.